# Determining GPS status javascript

Tags: javascript, html, gps, geolocation

I am developing an application using HTML5 GeoLocation. I have thus far managed to determine the users position once they have an active satellite connection.

Current code:

```
function requestPosition() {
    if (nav == null) {
        nav = window.navigator;
    }
    var geoloc = nav.geolocation;
    if (geoloc != null) {
        geoloc.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
    }
}
function successCallback(position) {
   //success gets location
}
function errorCallback(error) {
    // Check for known errors...outputs to screen
}
```

How would I be able to determine if there is an active connection to a satellite before I begin logging positions?

Note: I am not using phonegap currently, however, there is scope in the future to use phonegap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to call GPS until you have a success callback.

The interval delay must be under the geoloc timeout. 
In some case, maybe, the successCallback will be execute after setInterval, so you will have  2 successCallback.

```
 var interval;

function requestPosition() {
    if (nav === null) {
        nav = window.navigator;
    }
    var geoloc = nav.geolocation;
    if (geoloc !== null) {

        interval = window.setInterval(function () {
            geoloc.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {
                timeout: 4000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            });

        }, 5000);

    }
}

function successCallback(position) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    // Check for known errors...outputs to screen
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was toying with this idea initially but this helped to clear it up. Works brilliantly!